# nestjs set response ContentType as stream values

Tags: nestjs

with springboot you can send a stream of value (like sever-sent-event) to user with resposne content-type (@Response(produce = APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM_VALUE) so how use this with nestjs ???

Answer (score 0):

If i well understand your need, you can set the content type of the response to application/octet-stream. That will allow you to send a stream to the client like a file for example